# URIError in NuxtJS production when hosting on vercel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vercel

I am developing an application with ssr in nuxt. The problem I have is when I run "npm start" after doing the build and generate. The application starts working normally but when I try to log in it doesn't work although in development mode it works perfectly. The api is built with express and I am using tokens and nuxt auth as authentication method. The server endpoints declared in the auth strategy never get executed, use console.log () on the login endpoint handler to check. Anyone have any idea how I can solve this problem? Thanks for your time!

Login component script:

```html
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import index from './index.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    index,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['isAuthenticated']),
  },
  methods: {
    close() {
      this.$router.push('/')
    },
    login() {
      const button = document.querySelector('.center-form button')
      button.disabled = true
      button.innerHTML = '...'

      const data = { password: this.password, email: this.email }
      this.$auth
        .loginWith('local', { data })
        .then((x) => {
          this.$auth.strategy.token.set(x.data.token)
          this.$router.push('publicar-inmueble')
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Nuxt auth strategy:

```js
auth: {
  strategies: {
    local: {
      token: {
        property: 'token'
      },
      user: {
        property: 'user'
      },
      endpoints: {
        login: { url: '/server/api/usuarios/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'data' },
        user: { url: '/server/api/usuarios/mi-perfil', method: 'get', propertyName: 'data' },
        logout: { url: '/server/api/usuarios/logout', method: 'delete' }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Store:

```js
export const getters = {
  isAuthenticated(state) {
    return state.auth.loggedIn
  },

  loggedInUser(state) {
    return state.auth.user
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you set your env variables on production ?

Comment: I didn't, what .env variables should I create?

Comment: Where do you host your app? Wait, you don't use a `.env` file at all ? The URLs and so on, are hardcoded into your code?

Comment: The only .env variable I use is MONGODB_URI. I don't know what other .env variables I would need

Comment: Where do you host your app? `.env` is usually not tracked by git, hence if you deploy it to production, the platform will have no knowledge of your `.env` file.

Comment: The application is hosted by vercel. I did not know that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your app's settings on vercel, the URL should look like this:
`https://vercel.com/<your-username>/<your-project>/settings/environment-variables`

There, drop in your env variable (my screenshot is a value example!) and trigger a build of your app. Should work fine then.

[image]