# Notion API : "API token is invalid" on production (Vercel)

Tags: nuxt.js, vercel, nuxtjs3, notion-api, notion

I am working on a web platform using **Nuxt 3** and **Notion** as my backend through the [official API](https://developers.notion.com/reference/intro). I use it through this SDK : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@notionhq/client
Everything is working great on localhost:3000 but when I deploy my website to Vercel, I have this error message :

`WARN @notionhq/client warn: request fail { code: 'unauthorized', message: 'API token is invalid.' }`

It is really strange because I have the same `NOTION_API_KEY` (as localhost) inside my `.env`...

Here is my `package.json` :

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/supabase": "^0.1.16",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^5.1.2",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.2",
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.4",
    "sass": "^1.53.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.1",
    "@headlessui/vue": "^1.6.4",
    "@heroicons/vue": "^1.0.6",
    "@notionhq/client": "^2.2.1",
    "highlight.js": "^11.6.0",
    "vue-gtag-next": "^1.14.0"
  }
}
```

Have you ever encountered this scenario?

My Notion Token is invalid on production but working on localhost.

Comment: Inside your `.env` file on production or inside the environment variables on the dashboard? Not the same, should be the last one. As shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67389035/8816585

Comment: Thank you @kissu ! 
Do you know why my other variables (Google Analytics tracking + Supabase) are OK in production without having to put them in the Vercel dashboard ?

Comment: They are maybe hardcoded somewhere? Or you do have a fallback string matching the env variable? Docker/DevOps/CI pipeline, there can be various points where you could get those. Because there is no magic usually, if it's not there it will not work. Is your issue solved?